# Is is possible to create a network using supernetting like this?

Tags: network, subnet, topology

I need to create a network in the range 200.1.x.x and split it into 3 LANs which consist of 1250, 1750, and 1500 hosts respectively. This network should be able to expand to a total of 56 networks. Supernetting may be used in this process.

Is this possible? Because when I tried, I don’t think I have enough bits to do it. If possible, please elaborate on how to achieve this. Thank you!

Comment: This two-part answer will explain it all to you.

Comment: Hello @RonTrunk, thank you for the suggestion. I read through the two parts but am still confused because supernetting is not explained in the link. My main problem is if the network needs to expand to other 55 networks and if the design would be possible in this situation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *expand to 55 other networks*.  Perhaps you can show your work to see what's going on.

Comment: I apologize for being unclear. By expansion, I mean that I want to create the same topology and copy it 56 times, i.e. there will be 56 * (1250+1500+1750) hosts. But I still want to use the same ip range which 200.1.x.x. Is this realizable using supernetting? Thank you.

Comment: As you've described it, the answer is No.  But perhaps you misunderstood the original question.

Comment: Each of those lans need 11 bits. You have 16 bits to work with, so 2^(16-11) is 32.

Comment: Supernetting is really the wrong term for address aggregation. and there _is_ a section in [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) on address aggregation.

Comment: Thank y'all for answering. I understand now. And the term "address aggregation" sounds more suitable indeed.